# How to Add Dynamic Meta Tags Server Side with React.js and .NET Web API

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-web-api, meta-tags, facebook-share

I have built an application using React and .Net Web API. I'm pretty new at all this and without any previous knowledge on meta tags, I am now stuck on trying to implement a Facebook Share Button using dynamic meta tags.

I tried using react-helmet and react-snapshot but Facebook ignores the dynamic tags, and only accepts the url of the page. Now I've heard that it's possibly doable to replace the meta tags using the server side, but I'm not so sure I know how to do that in .Net.

I'm also aware of the option of using a framework such as Next.js, however, being so short on time, I was wondering if there exists a solution that doesn't include migrating.

Is there a way of making this work with the technology I am already using?

If anyone has had this problem before and is willing to help, or just knows the solution, I'd highly appreciate it! Thank you!